# Get the first li text with jquery in many li

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<li id="1">
     This is what I want to get
     <li id="2">
         not needed to be selected
         <li id = "3">
             not needed...
         </li>
     </li>
</li>
```

I want to get the li with id = 1 text with jQuery, this is what I have:

```
var id = "1"
var needed = $('li[id='+cat_id+']').text();
```

But this gets all the texts, how I could only get `This is what I want to get`.

**UPDATE**

You're right, that was wrong, so now it is:

```
<li id="1">
    This is needed
    <ul>
        <li id = "2">Not needed</li>
        <li id = "3"> Not needed too </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

in the above example how could I select `This is needed` considering it's id = "1"?

Comment: thats not valid markup. `li` inside `li` there should be `ul` inside `li`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var id = "1"
var needed = $('li[id=' + id + ']').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/h397T/

**EDIT 1**

As the other pointed out your html is wrong, it should be:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">This is what I want to get
        <ul>
            <li id="2">not needed to be selected
                <ul>
                    <li id="3">not needed...</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But even then my solution works, DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/h397T/1/

**EDIT 2**

It still works with your updated HTML, see DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/h397T/2/

Comment: Lol... I was not expecting this :)). Clearly his HTML is wrong, but this is a nice hack to get the text having this faulty HTML.

Comment: Well I didn't pay attention on his HTML. ;-)

Comment: @Simon nice idea, but it seems that I need to change my HTML

Answer (score 3):

your html is not correct. should be

```
<li id="1">
     This is what I want to get
</li>
<li id="2">
     not needed to be selected
</li>
<li id = "3">
     not needed...
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a structure like

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

try

```
$("ul li").first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li id="1">This is what I want to get
      <ul>
       <li id="2">not needed to be selected</li>
       <li id="3">not needed...</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var id = "#1"
var needed = $(id).children().detach();
$('#result').text($(id).text());
$(id).append(needed);
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h397T/3/)**

Comment: @mr this selected: `This is neededNot needed Not needed too `

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('li:first').text();
```